# Nested fields query by using mongo repository in java

Tags: java, mongodb

i want to get the value of Id by using mongorepository. Below example shows mondodb document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa4779f4a46b0f60a74313"),
    "_class" : "hello.mytest",
    "data" : {
        "type" : [ 
            {
                "testId" : "Id0",
                "usage" : "near",
                "additionalProperties" : {}
            }, 
            {
                "testId" : "Id1",
                "usage" : "far",
                "additionalProperties" : {}
            }]}
            }
```

when i try to find testId getting null value.

```
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<mytest, String> {
        List<data> findBytestId(String string);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add annotation to your method :

```
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<mytest, String> {
        @Query("{'data.type.testId': ?0}")
        List<data> findBytestId(String string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working , I have one doubt regarding mongo pojo class of mytest i.e if i set other field name with MsgId in  mongo pojo class, when i try to find that value getting no property found on mytest class, if i changed to msgId then i am getting value.what is the reason for this? for example  {
 "MsgId": "not getting value",
    "data" : {
        "type" : [ ]
            }}

Comment: it probably comes from Spring, which needs bean fields to have particular syntax (minus character as first, camelCase syntax, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

findBytestId => "testId" must be "TestId"

```
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<mytest, String> {
    List<data> findByTestId(String testId);
}
```